# How to get or build Superman Swimming bicycle?

Tags: identify-this-bike, build, framebuilding, theoretical

[Human body front area depending on pose](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/409917/is-the-terminal-velocity-in-air-independent-of-the-direction-of-the-movement#410190) in case it will be possible to ride in horizontal position drag must be way smaller as front area will be at least 5x smaller.

[Pardo](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/409917/is-the-terminal-velocity-in-air-independent-of-the-direction-of-the-movement#410190) face down HPV design.

[Prone bicycle](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prone_bicycle) or [archived](https://web.archive.org/web/20080510230316/http://www.encycleopedia.com/index.cfm?pid=23&edID=216) - that's it...

[This one seems to be produced still](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=K24dHLA8zpw)

Edit: Found similar prototype would like to get or build on YouTube [7 Crazy bikes](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=fGS2SgiLG80)

Is there anything between [Twicycle](http://twicycle.com/) and **[Streetflyer](http://www.streetflyer.info/)** [image: Streetflyer]
Or at least Streetflyer **with pedals** ? Strange why it is missing 'em ??

*Twicycle:*
[image: Twicycle]

Any hints for construction or building options ?

---

Comment: Assuming you mean Boardman's version of the "Superman" position, I very much doubt there is any specialist equipment, as the UCI banned it from competition so there would be almost no market for such a saddle.

Comment: Is there a question, or is this another link spam post? Why is there a identify-this-bike tag?

Comment: Can you read? Asking if concrete bike exists or how to build it, 4 question marks. Send that from mobile and did not found better tag on 4-5 pages. In case it exist, can someone tell me ? (Again question in case you did not mention question mark)

Comment: Tom, you linked to a 10-minute Youtube vid. Few people on the internet are willing to watch a whole 10 minute video to search for one item. You can link to a specific time in YouTube vids by clicking share, and checking the box that says share from a specific time. I think you mean something like the Streetflyer bike at 6m 33s in the vid. Clarify if not. Clearly, I'm one of those odd people who's willing to pore through some content, but you need to make it easier for others to understand what you're posting. https://youtu.be/fGS2SgiLG80?t=393

Comment: There is list and links in description, also Google can find that names easily and in case someone never seen them, would he know some similar? You can ignore that question in case you are not interested... Can improve that tomorrow from desktop but got few down votes from "haters" yet so probably useless anyway :-)

Comment: I removed "identify this bike" because there's no picture of a bike to identify.

Comment: @Tom please ask new questions as a new question, rather than editing a new question into an old one.

Comment: It is still the same question - face down bicycle constructions, your gang won the blocking chase yet, so there is no possibility to ask another even after I earned your down votes back. Btw there is a special saddle type for such bicycles named chest pad @Twicycle.

Comment: @Tom please understand I am not in a gang and having just checked, I have not down-voted a single one of your posts. I and several others have given suggestions on how to improve your questions inline with the norms of this site but you continue to ignore that advice. If you start to accept people's advice you might get more upvotes and be able to ask new questions.

Comment: @Tom if you mean mark as an accepted answer, you don't have to accept an answer on a question until you are satisfied. However, I would avoid calling answers "worthless" as it will probably offend someone, or deter other people from answering in case they think you won't appreciate their effort. There's lots of advice on the help pages, see https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/help/asking I would say do read the page on question bans for how to review and improve multiple questions: https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/help/question-bans

Comment: Remember that product recommendations are off-topic for the site, so if the question is basically, 'does such and such a product exist', then it's not going to go down well. Also, open-ended questions like 'any tips on how to do something' are hard to answer in a single posting so don't work well either

Comment: Site is also about building bikes (mentioned in help) and if you want to build something you probably look around if you are not reinventing wheel, do not want exact model or price, just was it already invented or not to see if it is reproducible or possible to build DIY and if someone manipulate or edit your question so that it fits his wrong understanding or answer, should I thank him for ? In case someone do any serious effort, I appreciate it, but if someone hunts for answering anything by copying something old or unrelated to get few more points - then sorry no.

Comment: Tom, this isn't a wiki or a blog. Please stop trying to use it as one. In particular, when a question has been closed as "too broad", then adding even more stuff to it doesn't help.

Comment: I cannot do anything even delete them - maybe I can try answer, but I am sure you or your "friends" are prepared on downvote button already ;-(

Comment: If you want to ask a new question, ask it as a new question. Don't edit an old question into something completely different.

Comment: You or your colleagues blocked me this option already.

Comment: @Tom Please see [Why are questions no longer being accepted from my account?](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/help/question-bans). We have repeatedly told you that the way you use this site is inappropriate. You completely ignored this and just complained and insulted us. Question bans are, as far as I'm aware, automatic. They happen very, very rarely. They are an indication that a user is _way_ out of line.

Answer (score 1):

There are two positions which could be called Superman.

1. [image]the Boardman one which has the arms pointing way forward like Superman in flight but the legs still pedal.  This is an aggressive aero timetrial position using a long stem and ski-pole length aerobars to reduce the angle of the upper arm respective to the incoming air - essentially reducing the effective frontal area.

Note his head is looking forward but his spine is flattish and angled down at the top.  This is a horribly uncomfortable position in which to ride.   Here thats okay because he's on a track with no road traffic (its likely he's alone on the track.)

The saddle in use is hard to see but its nothing special - he's still pedalling so a normal time-trial saddle will be used.  Weight is still important, but there are no climbs on a track.  Instead its all about getting the rider into their most aerodynamic position possible, and then allowing whatever comfort is possible without affecting their aero position.

2. there's the viral-video position which is essentially planking on the bike, coasting with one's legs out the back like an airplane tail.

[image: https://i.ytimg.com/vi/3Iz7ZMALaCY/hqdefault.jpg]

As you can see - that's Michael Guerra (left, in yellow) riding a vigorelli fixed gear road bike.  There's nothing special about his saddle, which can be glimpsed in the full video

In no way is this a good idea on a road, or anywhere uncontrolled.  Boardman's bike is a track bike, with no gears and no brakes.  This is workable because the track is isolated.

Doing this kind of thing on the road is foolish, and risks yourself, and worse, risks others.  Notice that any emergency reaction will have him off the bike because there is no third point of contact with the feet, and the saddle contact is only gravity.  At the end of the video, they have to divert around a mobility scooter and frankly have insufficient margin for error.

If you intend to ride like this on the road, just don't.

Comment: Both guys' gene sharing abilities might become slightly impaired. These two are rather candidates for the Darwin Award.